# How to convert HTML into PDF in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, pdf, pdf-generation, magento2

I want to convert HTML to PDF in my custom module in Magento 2. I don't want to use zend PDF. Is there any other method in Magento 2 which converts the HTML to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine has created a DomPDF module that you can use, see https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf

Comment: Hi,  how can i use this on default invoice print action on sale order grid.? please guide to do that..

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 (install lib)**

```
composer require setasign/fpdf:1.8.1 && composer require setasign/fpdi:2.0 && composer require knplabs/knp-snappy && composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 "0.12.4"
```

**step 2**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Helper\DPD;

require_once(BP.'/vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once(BP.'/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function getLabel( $shipmentId, $orderModel, $parcelNumbers ){

            try{
                $accountNumber = 'testing;
                $headers = array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Accept: text/html',
                    'GeoClient: account/' . $accountNumber,
                    'GeoSession: ' . $loginSession);
                $apiUrl = "URL here";
                $content = $this->apiCall($headers,$apiUrl, 'GET');
               
//                 echo $content;exit;
                $directory = 'path to save the file';
                $fileName = $orderModel->getIncrementId() .".pdf";
                try {

                    $snappy = new Pdf(\h4cc\WKHTMLToPDF\WKHTMLToPDF::PATH);
                    $FileNAme = $fileName;
                    $fullUrl = $directory . '/' . $FileNAme;
                    if (file_exists($fullUrl)) {
                        unlink($fullUrl);
                    }
                    $snappy->generateFromHtml($content, $fullUrl, array(
                        'orientation' => 'portrait',
                        'page-width' => '107',
                        'dpi' => 12399,
                        'page-height' => '107',
                        'lowquality' => false,
                        'margin-bottom'  => 0,
                        'margin-left'  => 0,
                        'margin-right'  => 0,
                        'margin-top'  => 0,
                        'zoom' => 1.23,
                        'encoding' => 'utf-8'
                    ));

                    $pdf = new FPDI('L','mm', array(107,107));
                    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($fullUrl); //the original file
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
                        $pageformat = array('Rotate' => 180);
                        $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                        $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);
                        // get original page orientation
                        $orientation = 'portrait';
                        $pdf->AddPage($orientation, '', 180);
                        $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                    }
                    $pdf->Output($fullUrl, "F");
                    $data = file_get_contents($fullUrl);

                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $Error = "Error Occur while getting the label from API : " . $e->getMessage();
                    $this->dpdErrors[] = $Error;
                    $this->mbDpdLog($Error);
                }

            }catch( exception $e ){
            }
        }
}
```